# Select element and work with it D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm testing with [this chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) and trying to click one line and hide the other two.

I tried different things but I don't find the way to do that. I can access to the data and log the names of the paths that I don't click but don't know how to reference the path and hide them for example

```
  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .on("click", function (d) {

        console.log("LOG:",cities[0].name);
        console.log("LOG:",d.name);
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            if(cities[i].name != d.name){
                console.log("LOG:",cities[i].name);
            }
        };      
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: NVD3 (in particular [this example](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html)) can give you a hint how to do this and may actually do what you want to already.

Comment: Have you tried putting something like: `$('.line').not(this).remove()` in the onclick callback

Comment: @tewathia it works! Than you!

Comment: @Filowk Change it to `$('.line').not(this).hide()` if you want to re-show the other lines(with `$('.line').show()` ) at some point